# SwiftUI .symbolEffect animation not working correctly

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have views like so when on tap of an image animation for that specific image should be triggered. However, it seems to be very inconsistent, for some reason triggering other images as well.

Am I missing something here?

[image: Animation]

```swift
struct ImagesView: View {
    
    let segments: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    @State private var selected: String = "1"
    @Namespace var name

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(segments, id: \.self) { segment in
                ZStack {
                    ImageView(tab: segment, selected: $selected)
                        .padding()
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct ImageView: View {
    
    var tab: String
    
    @Binding var selected: String
    @State var animate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "calendar")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .symbolRenderingMode(.monochrome)
            .symbolEffect(.bounce, value: animate)
            .onTapGesture {
                selected = tab
            }
            .onChange(of: selected) { _, newValue in
                withAnimation {
                    animate = newValue == tab
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation occurs whenever `animate` changes, not whenever it is `true`. Think about what images this line would cause an animation when you tap on an image.

```
animate = newValue == tab
```

For the image you tapped on, `animate` would be originally `false`, since the last time this was run, `newValue == tab` was false for it. Now, `newValue == tab` is `true`. So the image you tapped on is animated.

For the previously selected image, `animate` would be originally `true`, `newValue == tab` would be `false` because you selected a different image. This means that the previously selected image is also animated.

What you actually want is only change `animate` when `newValue == tab` is true.

```
if newValue == tab {
    animate.toggle()
}
```

(I'm not sure whether `animate` is a good name for this, perhaps `animationTrigger` is better)

Answer (score 0):

This might be work

```
Image(yourImage)
   .contentShape(Rectangle())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).